# Automatically generating pdf files from multiple latex files

Tags: pdftex, pdf, automation, python, pythontex

I generate 50 similar latex files through python. Now I need all these files as pdfs. Is there a way to do this automatically in some way? The file names are Version 1, ..., Version 50.

Example file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*} 
    \begin{array}{rl} 
    \min        & 2x_1 - 5x_2 + 1x_3 - 7x_4\\ [1ex] 
    \text{s.t.} & -4x_1 + 9x_2 + 1x_3 - 7x_4 = 0\\ [1ex]
    & 0 \leq x \leq 6
    \end{array} 
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: in bash, `for i in *.tex; do pdflatex $i; done`  other shells would be similar, or of course you could loop in python

Comment: Thank you, I could extend my python program such that it works :)

Answer (score 1):

in bash,

```
for i in *.tex; do pdflatex $i; done
```

other shells would be similar, or of course you could loop in python